# Find a value in an array

Tags: php, for-loop, return

What I am doing wrong with the following code? I want to compare if the element `$my_id` is present within the array `$arr`. If it is present return `TRUE` else return `FALSE`.

```
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
{
    if($arr[$i] == $my_id)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you expected it to do ? do you have an error ? is this php ?

Comment: Nothing, at least syntactically (if it is PHP). Why do you think there is something wrong? There might be logical errors but as you did not say what this is snippet supposed to do, we cannot help you with that. Which language is this? PHP?

Comment: its PHP . I want to compare if the element $my_id is present within the array $arr  . If it is present return TRUE else return FALSE

Comment: @Nitish, that's what the `in_array($my_id, $arr)` function is for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could replace that with...

```
return in_array($my_id, $arr);
```

...assuming you don't really want to return `FALSE` if the first element does not match.

If that is actually what you wanted, you could use...

```
return $arr[0] == $my_id;
```

If you want to leave your code mostly intact, just move the `return FALSE` to outside of the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is that you aren't looping entirely through the array.  You are returning true/false after the first item in the array, irrespective of subsequent array entries after [0]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe you should remove the else statement, unless you always just have one element in the array. I mean -- from the example you're showing, you're exiting the loop with this. I doubt this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know, *if* a value is within a given array

```
in_array($value, $array);
```

Maybe you want get the index of (the first occurence of) the value too

```
$index = array_search($value, $array);
if ($index === false) {
  // Not in array
} else {
  echo $array[$index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in Your code is to return false on `$arr[$i] != $my_id`. The algorithm should look something like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
{
    if($arr[$i] == $my_id)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
return FALSE;
```

P.S. This isn't the best solution for this problem in PHP language. You should use one from alex.